# Angular animate's classNameFilter with angular-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-animate, angular-bootstrap

I'll start that I have to use `$animateProvider.classNameFilter()` in my application. It speeds up everything.

In 0.12.* angular-bootstrap didn't use ngAnimate. So I was able to use `$animateProvider.classNameFilter(/animate/)` and everything from angular-bootstrap animated properly.

Now I'm migrating to a newer Angular and Bootstrap version. After changing library files, accordion and collapse stopped working. I found that above function caused my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/uGjQzKCy6hrj0V8MVBxD?p=preview (comment/uncomment line 4 in example.js).

What can I do to use this function properly? How should regex look like to cover all animations from ngAnimate and angular-bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

OPTION 1 - add `animate` class to every element that you want to animate with angular-bootstrap. Example using carousel

```
<div uib-carousel active="active" interval="-1" no-wrap="true">
  <div uib-slide class="animate" index="0">
    <img src="http://nick.mtvnimages.com/nick/video/images/nick/spongebob-050-full-episode-16x9.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Custom slide 1!!</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div uib-slide class="animate" index="1">
    <img src="http://nick.mtvnimages.com/nick/video/images/nick/spongebob-050-full-episode-16x9.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Custom slide 2!!</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div uib-slide class="animate" index="2">
    <img src="http://nick.mtvnimages.com/nick/video/images/nick/spongebob-050-full-episode-16x9.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Custom slide 3!!</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OPTION 2 - do not call `classNameFilter`. DISADVANTAGE: keep your HTML shallow, AKA make sure the elements that used to carry `animate` class are not nested in a parent div whose class/visibility will change, because `data-ng-animate` is applied to the topmost element and the internal function `areAnimationsAllowed` (angular-animate.js) will prevent the animation of any children.

PS. I wish angular-bootstrap provided some sort of configuration to work better with `classNameFilter`.